# Speed Up EventLogEntry.Message

Tags: .net, event-log

I am running into an interesting problem when using the System.Diagnostics namespace to read the application log off a server.  I am reading ~ 16,000 entries into another file for later use.  For example:

```
string logType = "Application";

EventLog ev = new EventLog(logType, "server name");
int LastLogToShow = ev.Entries.Count;
if ( LastLogToShow <= 0 )
Console.WriteLine("No Event Logs in the Log :" + logType);

int i;
for ( i = LastLogToShow - 1; i>= 0 ; i--)
{
     EventLogEntry CurrentEntry = ev.Entries[i];
     Console.WriteLine("Event ID : " + CurrentEntry.EventID);
     Console.WriteLine("Entry Type : " + CurrentEntry.EntryType.ToString());
     Console.WriteLine("Message : " + CurrentEntry.Message + "\n");
}
ev.Close();
```

Everything seems to be working just fine until I try writing the CurrentEntry.Message.  At this point the whole log goes from running in about a second to taking over a second for every 100 entries.  Does anyone have any creative solutions to speeding this up, or tricking the method into not checking for the correct dll every time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem isn't related to DLL checking but simple text rendering.  Event ID and Entry Type are small.  They can be written quickly.  Message is *BIG* and usually contains a lot of text, so screen rendering takes a long time.

Suggestion:  Create a StringBuilder and append all the text into it instead of repeated Console.WriteLines - then at the very end, do a single Console.WriteLine(myStringBuilder.ToStrion());

That may help.

Comment: To verify this is the problem, consider piping your output directly to a file.  If it takes significantly less time, then you found your problem.
C:\code\log\bin\debug>MyExe.exe >output.txt

Comment: I question the pipe to file approach as the output will be buffered and thus somewhat unpredictable, as file operations are generally more costly than memory operations.  Be interesting to see the results though.

Comment: If the Console.WriteLine are as slow on @Ben's computer as they are on mine, it could easilly be confused as disk IO time.  (Might make sure display drivers are up-to-date.)

Comment: Thats why I said use a stringbuilder - see how long it takes to get to the final output - its all in memory, so delays will be based purely on CurrentEntry.Message read times, and then the output will be straight from buffered memory so the write time will be based purely on Console.WriteLine.  The idea was to clearly break apart the two major variables in the processing time so you can tell which is the criminal.

Comment: Right.  That probably works better, but I suggested the > pipe-to-file option because it might be quicker to test.

Comment: I used a string builder (just populated a string builder, didn't write anywhere to remove that variable) and got the same behavior.  Runs very fast until I try to write the CurrentEntry.Message.  Everyone was right on the money that writing to the console is slow, but in this case was not the limiting factor.